# How to keep bees out of the Sukkah?

Tags: how-to, sukkot, bugs, honey

Many years (but not all), we have had bee problems in the Sukkah. This is probably caused by the fact that we continue to use honey for dipping the Challah throughout Sukkos.

What are some practical solutions for keeping them out? I would prefer to hear solutions that don't involve trapping/killing the bees.

Answer (score 7):

Use dryer sheets.  I personally use Bounce brand sheets.  Hang one for every 10 cubic feet or so, in a very bee infested area.  You probably won't need that many though. Adjust according to bee count.  (PS.  With the dryer sheets hung on some of the decorations, we actually leave honey out.  Its amazing!

Comment: From Skeptics.SE: [Do dryer sheets repel insects?](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/6548/408)

Answer (score 5):

I have heard that bugs don't like wind, including wind generated by fans. If you can get a running fan into your sukka, it could deter bugs from visiting.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the honey right after dipping. If you have many guests, you could keep it covered until the person dips his bread, then close the honey. You could also put a net on the door.

Comment: Re: net on door: they come through the s'chach (or cracks in between the schach and wall)

Comment: What yydl said; also, bees seem (in my _Sukos_ experience) highly attracted to things besides honey, such as juice and some foods.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry. Put bee traps a bit away from your sukkah.

Use liquor or unsweetened iced tea for kiddush during the daytime, instead of wine or grape juice.