# Which schools in the United States offer a Bachelors of Talmudic Law degree?

Tags: chinuch-education, adult-learning, yeshiva-school, college-university-school

There is a baccalaureate degree known as a [Bachelor of Talmudic Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bachelor_of_Talmudic_Law) (BTL) which some yeshivot award for post high school study. The requirements of this degree tend to vary by institution ([example](https://talmudicu.edu/educational-programs/)) I would like to know which schools in the United States offer this degree.

Comment: Is this on topic?

Comment: https://www.universities.com/programs/talmudic-studies-degrees

Comment: Keep in mind that many if not most colleges disregard this degree and will not count credits earned. Somewill accept partial credit.

Comment: @Double I think it can be considered on topic. Consider all the religious opinions one should not go to college. Many of those would allow an online degree. Some online colleges do in fact accept credits earned with a BTL. So in a roundabout way this information helps people who are living life according to (their preferred version of) Torah.

Comment: @DoubleAA any different than https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10644/how-to-keep-bees-out-of-the-sukkah - a topic that this stack would be uniquely qualified to answer

Comment: @rikitikitembo Yes it is different. What is "a topic that this stack would be uniquely qualified to answer"?